# Load 2 angularjs charts

Tags: angularjs, ajax, nvd3.js

Could you please help me understand how to load 2 angularJS charts in the same page in the same time.
E.g: These 2 charts:
plnkr.co/edit/UZGxhp?p=preview
and this one:
plnkr.co/edit/5vQOj9?p=preview

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Links to **plnkr.co** must be accompained by code, as required by the question editor. Please edit your answer so it meets those requirements.

Comment: Please find below the code for both graphs: